# Regarding already defined slots in arraylists

Tags: java, arraylist, slots

I'm wondering if it's possible to prefill the slots for an arraylist? For example, it is possible to fill out the st array by the assignment operation like this:

```
    student [] st = new student[3];
    st[0] = new student("214365879","eric banner", 67);
st[1] = new student("988634321","tony park",45);
st[2] = new student("009451223","paul summers",59);
```

But how is it possible by using arraylist instead?

Answer (score 2):

> It is possible to do by using add method from ArrayList

```
Person p1 = new Person("Izak","1234",33);
Person p2 = new Person("Igal","5668", 25);

List<Person> pList = new ArrayList<>();
pList.add(p1);
pList.add(p2);
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a constructor on `ArrayList` that takes an integer that tells the `ArrayList` the initial capacity.

Answer (score 0):

These are about as close as I can think to that sort of syntax.

```
List items = new ArrayList() {{
  add("A");
  add("B");
}};
```

Or

```
List items = Arrays.asList(new String[] { "A", "B" });
```